# How do I configure VS 2013 for LOCAL debug of Azure Web App with SSL

Tags: web-services, azure, ssl, iis, https

So I need to debug the startup of an Azure Web Role Service running MVC that has been configured to use SSL.

Ive got the endpoints set in the .csdef , I'm running in Admin mode, I've got IIS Express selected.

My app gets to Application_Start()  where it successfully

```
RegisterAllAreas();
ConfigureIdentity();
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfig);
RegisterRoutes();
RegisterBundles();
```

App_start returns successfully - and the next thing I hit is the App_error exception

ID1059: Cannot Authenticate the user because the URL Scheme is not https and requiredSSL is set to True in the configuration.

the URL showing is http:  //  localhost:4680  which I know is wrong since it should be https  since for the WebApp project I've got the following properties set
SSL Enabled = True
SSL URL - https:  //  localhost:44303
URL is http:  //  localhost4680

If I right click on the WebApp project and go to the WEB tab, under Servers I've got set IIS as the server
projectURL is http:  //  localhost:4680

I've tried changing the Project URL to
https:   //  localhost:4680
https:  //  Localhost:444
https:  //  localhost:443
https:  //  localhost:44300
https:  //  Localhost:44303

and all of those blow up before they get to Application_start()

I've tried googling this everywhere and I know what I'm missing is something really simple.  but for the life of me I cannot remember what it is (I've not had to debug this in 6 mos - and I'm more of a back-end SQL server guy)

Comment: What's the default project in your solution - Is it the cloud services one or the web application?

Comment: I'm using a cloud service